# Where is the "proper" place to initialize class variables in AS3

Tags: variables, initialization, declaration, actionscript-3

Is it "better" to initialize AS3 class variables in the class constructor?  Or can I just initialize them to their default value when I declare them at the top of my class?  I ask because when there's a lot of class variables, it appears inefficient to declare them in one place and then initialize them in another when I could easily do both in the same place.  It one option is better than the other, why?

Thanks!

eg:

initializing in constructor

```
class foo {
    var bar:Boolean
}

function foo():void {
    bar = true;
}
```

OR

initializing with the declaration

```
class foo {
    var bar:Boolean = true;
}

function foo():void {
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally recommend initialization inside the constructor for two reasons:

1. You cannot initialize objects that depend on other *var* objects having already been created before construction.
2. It's easier to locate and understand initialization code when it's properly procedural. Especially when you (I) dive back into big classes I haven't opened for months.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I don't do either! I like to create an "init" function that initializes everything. That means if I need to reset the instance to its default, I can just call the init method at anytime.

Comment: I agree with this, ten years later :D